# Is there a way to filter using both 'AND' and 'OR' for a python data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a Pandas data frame using a series of conditions in python.

```
filtered_df = data[(data['Dependant'].isnull())|(data['cust2_status']=='closed'), (data['cust1_status']== 'active')]
```

I was hoping to get a subset of rows were dependant = null OR customer 2 = 'closed' AND customer 1 = 'active'. The error I am receiving is "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed".

Comment: Looks like you're missing a bitwise `AND`

Comment: `df[(data['Dependant'].isnull()|(data['cust2_status']==('closed')))&(data['cust1_status']== 'active')]` ?

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I am new to python, I thought that adding another condition via the comma is assumed to be an &

Comment: @DominicNaimool no problem my friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Docs: [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
filtered_df = data.loc[(((data['Dependant'].isnull()|(data['cust2_status']=='closed')) & (data['cust1_status']== 'active'))]
```

Comment: `.loc[]` not required here. :)